# Inserting a new Node at the Beginning of a Linked List

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I was writing a code for inserting a node in the beginning of a linked list, but i'm not able to recognize why the function is not adding the data .

```
void insert(Node* head) {
    Node* n = new Node();
    cout << "Enter the data to be added in beggining";
    cin >> n->data;
    n->next = head;
    head = n;
}
```

Full Source Code :

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node;                                 //Forward Declaration

int create(Node*);
void insert(Node*);                         //Function Prototyping
void show(Node*);

class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

int main() {
    Node* head;
    head = new Node();
    create(head);
    insert(head);
    show(head);

    return 0;
}
//Fucntion to create a list
int create(Node* n) {
    char c;
    cout << "Enter Data to be stored" << endl;
    cin >> n->data;
    cout << "Press 0 to exit" << endl;
    cin >> c;
    if (c == '0') {
        n->next = NULL;
        return 0;
    }
    n->next = new Node();
    n = n->next;
    create(n);
}
//Function to insert a item in list
void insert(Node* head) {
    Node* n = new Node();
    cout << "Enter the data to be added in beggining";
    cin >> n->data;
    n->next = head;
    head = n;
}
//Function to show list
void show(Node* n) {
    while (n != NULL) {
        cout << n->data << endl;
        n = n->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you insert a new node at the beginning -- the list address changes becoming the address of the new node. You cannot pass a simple pointer -- as the function receives a *Copy Of* the pointer and any changes made to the pointer address are lost on function return. In C++, you can pass a reference to the pointer or pass the address of the pointer and then operate on the original pointer address directly in `insert()`. You may find [Singly Linked List (node only, no wrapper)](https://pastebin.com/5MPLU4wB) useful. It is C, but for your purpose here it won't matter.

Comment: Only the address of head would change right ?

Comment: Correct. You are just adding a new node to the front of the list. So since your list now starts with that new node, the list address is now the address of that node.